# Gradle - using flavors

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I have a project that uses Bluetooth Low Energy scanning in a single class. Since API 21, Android has deprecated a few of the methods I use, and wants me to replace them with new ones. I don't really want to cut off all the API 19s and 20s out there, so I'm trying to research into the Gradle flavors.

What I've found so far is that in order to create different flavors, you need two different packages for the two flavors that contain the different source code.

My question is: Should I try to use flavors if I only need the variance in a single class? Also, how should I go about doing it? I've looked at the Gradle docs, and there's not much but how to declare different flavors, and not that much on the actual setup.

I found this in the section for [flavors](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/nativeBinaries.html#flavors),

> a library is defined with a 'english' and 'french' flavor. When compiling the 'french' variant, a separate macro is defined which leads to a different binary being produced.

but that's about as far as it goes. How would I actually set up the binary and the changes? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of a gradle flavor:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs { ... }
    buildTypes { ... }
    productFlavors {
        demo {
            applicationId "com.buildsystemexample.app.demo"
            versionName "1.0-demo"
            buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'isDemo', 'true'
        }
        full {
            applicationId "com.buildsystemexample.app.full"
            versionName "1.0-full"
            buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'isDemo', 'false'
        }
    }
}
```

You can put different source code for each build flavor.

Just read this page: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

Comment: Yes but is there a way for me to retain the same package layout, but tell gradle to treat two _files_ as different flavors. All code is the same except for those two flavors

Comment: Create a build config field and create different values for each build type and create an if in the code with te field. I have updated the answer.

Comment: so then would you use if(isDemo) in the file to determine if it was the demo or not?

Comment: Yes. if(BuildConfig.isDemo) {}.

Comment: @Jeeter this answer is correct and will work just fine, but maintaining two separate APKs can be a pain in the butt. Have a look at my answer if you want an alternative.

Comment: @SandroMachado I'm getting the error that the DSL method buildConfigField() isn't found

Comment: Should be: buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'isDemo', 'true' I have updated the Answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with flavors, but since it's only a single class I'd recommend doing something like this instead:

First, make an interface:

```
public interface Something{
    //Put anything that will be common to both classes here.
    public void doSomething();
}
```

Create two classes that implement the interface. One that uses the new and exciting versions:

```
public class SomethingWithNewStuff implements Something{
    @Override
    public void doSomething(){
        //Go nuts and use new fancy features where you need them
    }
}
```

Then override the methods that need updating for older versions:

```
public class LegacySomething implements Something{
    @Override
    public void doSomething(){
        //do something in a legacy way.
    }
}
```

Then, when you instantiate the class:

```
Something something;

int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
    something = new SomethingWithNewStuff();
} else{
    something = new LegacySomething();
}

something.doSomething();
```

Depending on what you're doing specifically, you could implement the same sort of thing in a number of ways. In certain cases it may be better to have one class extend the other instead of having both inherit from a common interface, etc.

Either way, in the end this will probably be less work than maintaining two separate builds for a small change.